# How to access Encoder.Default.HtmlEncode method from code library in Asp.Net 5 (core) mvc solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, nuget-package, asp.net-core-1.0

I have an Asp.Net 5 (core) solution using Asp.Net 5 RC1 in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 which has two projects, an Asp.net 5 website project and a "Class Library (Package)" project.

I would like to be able to call the following method from within my class library:

```
 HtmlEncoder.Default.HtmlEncode(text)
```

However, I can't figure out what reference needs to be set on the project to make the method available.  I have noticed that I can access the method from the Asp.net 5 (core) website project if I add the following using statement to the file containing the method call:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders;
```

But when I try to add this using statement to a file in the class library project Visual Studio indicates that no such namespace exists due to a missing project reference.

I've searched and searched and I can't figure out what project reference is needed to access that namespace. I assume it's a nuget package reference that's needed but when I go to "Manage NuGet Packages" for the project, the list of available packages is empty.

What project reference do I need and how can I get it?

[image: Intellisense is complaining about the method and the using statement. The website project is called Learning and the class lib is called Helpers][image: I don't have any options for adding nuget packages for the project!?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a reference to `"Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders ": "1.0.0-rc1-final"` in your project.json

Comment: Agua from mars - How did you know it was Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders rather than Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.Core?  Also do you have any idea why Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders doesn't show up when I try to browse nuget packages (2nd screenshot?)

Comment: I looked into MVC dependencies and github repository under aspnet. I don't why it didn't show up when you try to browse nuget package.

Answer (score 3):

I have just installed the ASP.NET Core version and I have the same problem with a sample provided by Microsoft in a doc called ASP.NET MVC 6 Documentation, Release.

The solution I found is :

Replace
using Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders;
by
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;

And replace
return HtmlEncoder.Default.HtmlEncode(
by
return HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(

and it works !